# Install Moodle plugin into root directory or redirect it

Tags: php, redirect, plugins, path, moodle

I'm in the process of programming my own static pages in moodle. It works so far, but I have the whole thing running in the local environment in its own folder in the root directory "mymoodle.com/folder/".

Now I would like to install it as a plugin on the stable instance via the dashboard/frontend, but if I understand it correctly then only works with the available plugin types => path from the [docu](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Plugin_types)

Is that only possible via FTP access? Or is a plugin type not listed yet or have I overlooked one?

Is there a better moodle approach than plugin type "local" ?

I have already discovered the ["Static Pages"](https://github.com/moodle-an-hochschulen/moodle-local_staticpage) plugin, but I don't really understand how they solve the redirect from /local/staticpage/ to /static/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local Plugin folder is the best approach, if you are creating a plugin that doesn't comes under any of the other plugin types mentioned [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Plugin_types#List_of_Moodle_plugin_types).

However you can shift the folder (and make appropriate changes in files to require files) under the Moodle's root directory and it should work.